# Is there a way to load an image in the canvas object without using javascript?

Tags: html5-canvas

I've tried using the image tag inside .  I've also tried sourcing the image straight into the canvas via .

Comment: Purely curious...why without javascript? :)

Comment: It's simply the way I wanted the code structure to read.  <canvas> would be a more natural extension of HTML to me if they did actually do this.

Comment: You will eventually be able to use the document.register capability of Web Components extend <canvas> or event create your own custom html element.  It's not ready for prime-time yet, but there are several polyfills available now like: http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/custom-elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. All drawing must be done using javascript. Please refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp).